# Sefardi/Mizrahi rulings on non-Orthodox denominations

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, heterodox, non-rabbinic-judaism

I'm aware why Chatam Sofer and R Feinstein had such harsh and castigating stances on associating/celebrating with non-Orthodox Jews or entering those prayer spaces, as they were actively fighting the advances of Reform (and later Conservative). I'm curious what Sefardi/Mizrahi sources say on non-Orthodox Jews and entering their prayer spaces, seeing as how denominations never took root among Sefardim/Mizrachim.

Comment: By the same token the premodern sefardi leaders were also much less likely to have had reason to comment about some wacky things some Ashkenazim up north were doing

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Double AA--eventually they would have to wrestle with it, no? nowadays, for example, what answers would be given around attending a function at a reform/conserv/etc shul?

Comment: I believe Ashkenazim also let you attend such functions. The issue was forming associations with them.